# Looping through to update list

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck at a point where I need to range a1 to a50 with 5 names in cells c1to c5.

Below is the Code which is not working. I need to get the range in Cells C1 to c5 looping , I mean when range(a5 gets filled with c5 value),A6 should get range c1 value.
Let me know if I not clear. Below is the code for ref

```
Sub test()
For x = 2 To 5
For k = 2 To 50
Range("a" & k).Value = Range("C" & x).Value
k = k + 1
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Sub Test()
   k = 1

   For x = 1 To 50
      Range("a" & x).Value = Range("C" & k).Value
      k = k + 1
      If k > 5 Then k = 1
   Next
End Sub
```